# verilog event control utilizing iff qualifier

Tags: system-verilog

This Systemverilog [tutorial](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/procedure_ctrl3.html#Event_control) lists interesting always block event control statements that utilize the iff qualifier.

I don't understand the first 3 simulation results for @1 and @2:

```
@0 clk 0 rst 0 enable x d x q x latch x
@1 clk 1 rst 0 enable x d 0 q 0 latch x
Reset is asserted with iff
Reset is asserted, no iff
@2 clk 0 rst 1 enable x d 0 q 0 latch x
Reset is asserted, no iff
```

Namely, why is reset triggering the $display statements @1 when there hasn't been a posedge rst?
Also, why isn't $display(Reset is asserted with iff) triggered @2 when rst becomes 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$display()` messages are being printed at time `@2`. The simulator scheduler executes the `$display()` messages when the lines are reached. The `$monitor()` message is only printed at the end of the time step. Therefore, within the same time step, `$display()` messages will be printed before the `$monitor()` message. Add `$time` to the `$display` messages to help visualize this.

The final `Reset is asserted, no iff` is not part of time 2, but time 3. When the clock has a rising.

> `@3 clk 1 rst 1 enable x d 0 q 0 latch x`

The "with iff" message is not displayed because `iff rst == 0` masks the `posedge clk` from being observed when `rst !=0`. The `posedge clk` can only be observed when `iff` condition is true.

Do note that `iff` is not synthesizable, so do not put it in a design. The feature is for verification and behavioral modeling.

Comment: Thanks. I had my events regions mangled. Your comment made me realize that the first 2 $display() messages belonged to the @2 timestep. Those $display() commands are printed in the active event region while the $monitor() executes at the postponed event region (end of @2 simulation timestep). Some well inserted newline characters would have made it easier to visualize which display statements belong to which timestep.